# How do I apply complicated algebraic/trigonometric manipulations to nested expressions?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

Consider the expression
$$ a\sin(x)-a\sin\left(\frac{x}{a}\left(a+\frac{ay}{x}\right)\right) \label{a}\tag{1} $$
which can be rewritten as
$$ \sin(x)-\sin\left(x+y\right) \label{b} \tag{2} $$
and finally as 
$$ -2 \sin(y/2) \cos(x+y/2) \label{c} \tag{3} $$
I have a more complicated expression, where an expression such as (\ref{a}) is **embedded**. I want Mathematica to apply the transformation "(\ref{b}) -> (\ref{c})" to this expression, without any further simplifications. Note that the variable names may differ and I want to inform Mathematica about "(\ref{b}) -> (\ref{c})" in the general most way. That is for example, without the prefactor $a$ in (\ref{a}) or without giving the explicit structure of the parentheses in the $\sin$ on the right hand side of (\ref{a}).

Answer (score 4):

```
a Sin[x] - a Sin[x/a (a + a y/x)] // FullSimplify // TrigFactor
```

It works also as

```
g[a Sin[x] - a Sin[x/a (a + a y/x)]] /. g[a_] :> g[TrigFactor[FullSimplify[a]]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work if the difference of the sines is wrapped inside `Exp`.

Comment: Or basically, the expression to simplify is wrapped in any other expression.

Comment: Please. See the example attached.

Comment: If `g` is `Exp` I have to explicitly use `Exp` on the right hand side of `/.`, otherwise this still does not work. Furthermore, if there are other things wrapped around the `Sin`es this still does not work, e.g.: `Exp[t + a Sin[x] - a Sin[x/a (a + a y/x)]] /. 
 Exp[x_] :> Exp[TrigFactor[ExpandAll[x]]]`. I guess that's because the sines are wrapped in something because of the `+`.